# Create button only for certain group

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-10

I want to make the create button only show for certain group. Here is my xml code

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="sales_forecast_view_tree">
        <field name="name">sales.forecast.tree</field>
        <field name="model">sales.forecast</field>
        <field name="priority" eval="16"/>
        <field name="groups_id" eval="[(4,ref('ts_addons_tbk.group_tbk_exim'))]"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="Sales Forecast" version="7.0"  >
                <field name="name" />
            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>
```

What shoukd I do?

Comment: In simplest form, you can create an access right entry in the access file, and grant create rights to your desired group

Answer (score 0):

In order di hide create button, it more easy to set the group in setting menu > Database Structure > Models
So no need to edit the script